# $u-\Delta u\in L^2 \Rightarrow u\in L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove that solutions to $u-\Delta u = f,\quad f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) $, where $u$ vanishes at infinity, are in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I'm not sure this is true. So is the statement in the title correct for $u$ vanishing at infinity?

Take for example $n = 1$. Since $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (u-u'')^2 = \int u^2+u''^2-2uu'' <\infty,$ proving $\int uu''<\infty$ will suffice. Well, $$\int_{-x}^xuu'' = |_{-x}^x uu' - \int_{-x}^x(u')^2, $$ so $\int_{-\infty}^\infty uu''+(u')^2 = 0$. So it also suffices to show $u'\in L^2.$ However I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Fourier transform $\widehat u = \frac{1}{1+|2\pi x|^2} \widehat f$ so
$$
\|u\|_{L^2} = \|\widehat u\|_{L^2} = \|\tfrac{1}{1+|2\pi x|^2} \widehat f\|_{L^2} \leq \|f\|_{L^2}.
$$